# Getting the value from cell

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I want to get the value (T28200006) from Range("C6").

I get this error:

[image]

```vb
Public Sub INFO_PROTO1(ByRef strQ As String)

Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset, numero_de_police

If Len(numero_de_police) > 0 Then
    RECSET.Open " select sousc.is_produit as b_perf_cma from db_dossier sousc,db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
        " where sousc.no_police = " & numero_de_police & "  and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and " & _
        " sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit  ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    
    With Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine")
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query value is not a number, so you need to quote it in your SQL:

```
..." where sousc.no_police = '" & numero_de_police & "'  and...
```